# Using dependencyManagement with a local in project repository

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that is structured kind of like this:

```
parent-project
|-pom.xml
|
|-proj-A
|   |-pom.xml
|
|-proj-B
|   |-pom.xml
|
|-proj-C
|   |-pom.xml (1)
|   |-lib (2)
|   |-proj-C-child-A
|      |-pom.xml (3)
|   |-proj-C-child-B
|      |-pom.xml (3)
```

*proj-A* and *proj-B* are both independent submodules of the parent-project.

*proj-C* has multiple sub-modules that depend on unmanaged libraries that cannot be retrieved from a remote repository.

I tried to:

1. import these JARs ([using these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies)) into the **"lib (2)"** folder shown above.

   ```bash
   mvn deploy:deploy-file \
       -Durl=<path-to-proj-C>/lib \
       -Dfile=<path-to-the-external-jar> \
       -DgroupId=<groupId-for-jar> \
       -DartifactId=<artifactId-for-jar> \
       -DrepositoryId=lib \
       -Dversion=<version-for-jar>
   ```
2. Add a `<repositories>` section to the **proj-C pom.xml (1)**

   ```xml
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>lib</id>
           <name>local-filesystem-repository</name>
           <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
           <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```
3. Add the dependency to the `<dependencyManagement>` section in **proj-C pom.xml (1)**

   ```xml
   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>my-shiny-jar</groupId>
               <artifactId>shiny-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   ```
4. Add dependency in the **child modules (3)** `<dependencies>` section

   ```xml
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>my-shiny-jar</groupId>
           <artifactId>shiny-api</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

This does not work. It fails to get the dependencies because it is looking for them in the submodule's lib directory instead of the parent where the repository is defined.

```
Downloading: file://<path-to-proj-C>/proj-C-child-A/lib/...
...
...Could not find artifact <groupId>:<version> in lib 
    (file://<path-to-proj-C>/proj-C-child-A/lib) -> [Help 1]
```

It looks like it is using the project being built rather than the project where it is defined for the substitution of `file://${project.basedir}/lib` in the `<repositories>` element.

What is the best way to deal this without using a remote repository?

Comment: Maybe the [non-maven-jar-maven-plugin](https://github.com/stephenc/non-maven-jar-maven-plugin) could do the trick?

Comment: What is so hard to just simply upload the artifacts to your repository manager and that's it?

Comment: @khmarbaise That is eventually what I did. I was waiting on another team to get a repository manager (Nexus) setup and it took a lot longer than expected. I wanted to find a way to deal with it in the meantime.